# Android Studio App crash whenever I click on login button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

LoginActivity.java

```
package com.example.videocalling;
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
FirebaseAuth auth;
EditText emailBox, passwordBox;
Button loginBtn, signupBtn;
ProgressDialog dialog;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    emailBox = findViewById(R.id.emailbox);
    passwordBox = findViewById(R.id.passwordbox);

    loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
    signupBtn = findViewById(R.id.createbtn);

    loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dialog.show();
            String email, password;
            email = emailBox.getText().toString();
            password = passwordBox.getText().toString();

            auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull  Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity.class));
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"Logged in", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, task.getException().getLocalizedMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }
            });

        }
    });

    signupBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, SignupActivity.class));
        }
    });
  }
}
```

DashboardActivity.java

```
package com.example.videocalling;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeet;
import org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetActivity;
import org.jitsi.meet.sdk.JitsiMeetConferenceOptions;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

public class DashboardActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
EditText CodeBox;
Button joinBtn, shareBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_dashboard);

    CodeBox = findViewById(R.id.codeBox);
    joinBtn = findViewById(R.id.joinbtn);
    shareBtn = findViewById(R.id.sharebtn);

    URL serverURL;


    try {
        serverURL = new URL("https://meet.jit.si");
        JitsiMeetConferenceOptions defaultOptions =
                new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
                        .setServerURL(serverURL)
                        .setWelcomePageEnabled(false)
                        .build();
        JitsiMeet.setDefaultConferenceOptions(defaultOptions);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    joinBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            JitsiMeetConferenceOptions options = new JitsiMeetConferenceOptions.Builder()
                    .setRoom(CodeBox.getText().toString())
                    .setWelcomePageEnabled(false)
                    .build();

            JitsiMeetActivity.launch(DashboardActivity.this, options);
        }
    });

   }
}
```

I Got This Error
2022-02-20 18:43:04.434 14176-14176/com.example.videocalling E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.videocalling, PID: 14176
java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(119070000bytes) bitmap.
at android.view.DisplayListCanvas.throwIfCannotDraw(DisplayListCanvas.java:229)
at android.view.RecordingCanvas.drawBitmap(RecordingCanvas.java:97)
at android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable.draw(BitmapDrawable.java:529)
at android.view.View.getDrawableRenderNode(View.java:19381)
at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:19317)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19114)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18064)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:18851)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4214)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4000)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:19126)
at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.draw(DecorView.java:785)
at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:18073)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:643)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:649)
at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:757)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2980)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2794)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2347)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1386)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6733)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:911)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:723)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:658)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:897)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Error :line No 44-startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, DashboardActivity .
When i click login button app crash

Comment: At which particular line of code are you getting that error?

Comment: When you get an error message, I recommend searching for that error as it's likely come up before. Here's other [questions about the error message you get](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bandroid%5D+Canvas%3A+trying+to+draw+too+large).